# Difference between views-to-content-type attaching modules

Tags: 7, views, entities

For D7, there are a number of good options for attaching a view to a node, including

- [EVA](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva)
- [Viewfield](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewfield)
- [View reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewreference)

Is EVA a superset of the functionality of the other options? What exactly is the difference between them?

Comment: No straight answer https://www.drupal.org/node/1299222